# Showing image in GridView from the database?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have images saved in SQL server database as a binary data. Now I want to show these images in the Gridview. But there web control which directly read the data from the database. Web image control requires `ImageUrl` property so can not use this as my images are in databases. However i can store the images in a folder but i want some different way which directly read image data from the database and show in a grid.

Comment: Have you done a search of existing answers in SO?

Comment: Yes, i did but cant find appropriate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+images+database+httphandler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using generic handler you can convert binary data into image and display it

**Code:**
Set image control url as
`Image1.ImageUrl = "~/ShowImage.ashx?id=" + id;`

where ShowImage.ashx is a generic handler file.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class ShowImage : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
       Int32 empno;
       if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
            empno = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["id"]);
       else
            throw new ArgumentException("No parameter specified");

       context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
       Stream strm = ShowEmpImage(empno);
       byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
       int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);

       while (byteSeq > 0)
       {
           context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
           byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
       }      
       //context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
    }

    public Stream ShowEmpImage(int empno)
    {
        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
        string sql = "SELECT* FROM  table WHERE empid = @ID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", empno);
        connection.Open();
        object img = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        try
        {
            return new MemoryStream((byte[])img);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it directly fetch the image from the handler ?

Comment: @eraj: yes this works in my case. well jst try once and let me knw if u find any issues ?

Answer (score 0):

the blog may give you some help
http://hi.baidu.com/pxvddcbpbrbmqxq/item/3de72787e9e1c6eae496e098