# Retrieve image from database in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, httphandler

How to retrieve images from sql database in asp.net using c#.

i want to retrieve the image file from database  and then display the image in a  tag.

i try this code but it is not working

### aspx

```
 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="" Height="150px" Width="165px" />
```

### code behind

```
 Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["image"];
 Response.Buffer = true;
 Response.Charset = "";
 Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
 Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
 Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
 Response.Flush();
 Response.End();
```

How to give link to the `ImageUrl=""` of this image???

Comment: Define `not working`, what errors are you getting?

Comment: Oh and MIME is `image/jpeg` not `image/jpg`.

Comment: Is this a page or a generic handler (ashx)?

Comment: You also need Response.Clear()

Comment: How to give link to the ImageUrl="" of this image???

Comment: @dtryon sy "Student.aspx"

Comment: @AhmadAbbasi That is a filename not a URI.  However, if you are returning the image by addressing this `http://domain/Student.aspx` then your ImageUrl would be this: `http://domain/Student.aspx`.

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=129

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987433/display-image-from-database-in-asp-net-with-c-sharp

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a `generic http handler` as follows

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class ShowImage : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
       Int32 empno;
       if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
          empno = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["id"]);
       else
          throw new ArgumentException("No parameter specified");

       context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
       Stream strm = ShowEmpImage(empno);
       byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
       int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);

       while (byteSeq > 0)
       {
           context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
           byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
       }       
       //context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
    }

    public Stream ShowEmpImage(int empno)
    {
         string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EmployeeConnString"].ConnectionString;
         SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
         string sql = "SELECT empimg FROM EmpDetails WHERE empid = @ID";
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,connection);
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", empno);
         connection.Open();
         object img = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
         try
        {
            return new MemoryStream((byte[])img);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
       {
            connection.Close();
       }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
             return false;
        }
    }


}
```

and display image as follow

```
 Image1.ImageUrl = "~/ShowImage.ashx?id=" + id;
```

There are some links below 
[Showing image in GridView from the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432381/showing-image-in-gridview-from-the-database)
[How to show a image in database in the image control of Asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482104/how-to-show-a-image-in-database-in-the-image-control-of-asp-net)
[Display image from database in ASP.net with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987433/display-image-from-database-in-asp-net-with-c-sharp)
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=129

Comment: I'd be interested on your opinion on whether to set IsReusable to true or false and why?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is the right approach.
You should not embed image into html, and this is not the right way anyway.

I suggest adding an ashx (generic handler) and use it to generate the image from query string, then ini the page use something like

```
<asp:Image ImageUrl='GetImage.ashx?id=12345' ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: With Entity Frame work]

[With SQL (Code Project)](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1183317/How-to-display-image-on-aspx-page-from-database-in)

```
<asp:Image ID="ImgProfilePic" runat="server"  />

    byte[] imagem = (byte[])(dr["IMG"]);
string PROFILE_PIC = Convert.ToBase64String(imagem);
ImgProfilePic.ImageUrl = String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", PROFILE_PIC);
```