# displaying image (from database) in an image control

Tags: asp.net

Triyng to retrieve and display image from database in an image control based on employeeid...
I have taken an httphandler in which i have this:

```vb
  Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

    'context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    'context.Response.Write("Hello World!")

    Dim employeeId As Integer
    If (Not (context.Request.QueryString("employeeId")) Is Nothing) Then
        employeeId = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString("employeeId"))
    Else
        Throw New ArgumentException("No parameter specified")
    End If
    Dim imageData() As Byte = {}
    ' get the image data from the database using the employeeId Querystring
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
    ' You can retrieve this also from the database
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(imageData)

End Sub

Protected Sub DisplayButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles DisplayButton.Click
    bind()
    GridView1.Visible = "True"
    ProcessRequest(Context)
End Sub
```

Error: `The 'MasterPageFile' property can only be set in or before the 'Page_PreInit' event.`
Where am I going wrong? What all changes do i need to make?

This is the image control on the form:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" imageUrl="HttpHandler.ashx?employeeId=5"/>
```

@Stefano Altieri:

This is on Employee.aspx

```
Protected Sub DisplayButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles DisplayButton.Click
    bind()
    GridView1.Visible = "True"
    Image1.ImageUrl = "~/HttpHandler.ashx?EmployeeID='" & EmailIDTextBox.Text & "'"
End Sub
```

and this is on HttpHandler.ashx

```
Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

    'context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    'context.Response.Write("Hello World!")

    Dim employeeId As Integer
    If (Not (context.Request.QueryString("employeeId")) Is Nothing) Then
        employeeId = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString("employeeId"))
    Else
        Throw New ArgumentException("No parameter specified")
    End If
    Dim imageData() As Byte = {}
    ' get the image data from the database using the employeeId Querystring
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
    ' You can retrieve this also from the database
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(imageData)

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know the line where the exception is thrown?

Comment: when i call ProcessRequest (i.e. when it should go to the httphandler (.ashx page))

Comment: Also... I am a little confused... is this a page or an http handlers? It can't be both.. you have to implement http handlers in a separate ashx file

Comment: Take a look at my answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935205/retrieve-image-from-database-in-asp-net/14935469#14935469

Comment: i have. i have implemented the handler on an ashx page... the above code is on the employee page on which i have the display button to display employee image...

Comment: I don't think this will ever work. You have to separate the things and call the handler using the ImageUrl propery of an image. Ie. ImageUrl=GetImage.ashx?employeeId=123

Comment: thats what i am doing there
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" imageUrl="HttpHandler.ashx?employeeId=5"/>
its not working.... the name of my handler is HttpHandler.ashx... hope am explaining it clearly...

Comment: No, you are mixing page and handler code. Can you post the codes (and the pagne/handler file names?

Comment: I have posted the page and handler names with corresponding codes. Now I have this:
Error - "Input string was not in a correct format!"

Comment: Ok,you don't need to quote the id in query string ('" & EmailIDTextBox.Text & "'")

Comment: Use: Image1.ImageUrl = "~/HttpHandler.ashx?EmployeeID=" & EmailIDTextBox.Text

Comment: removed the quotes... still the same error...

Comment: As a general hint... can you provide the line where the exception is thrown?

Comment: employeeId = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString("employeeId"))

its the third line in the handler...

Comment: So the parameter is not an integer! Try using the debugger to see the value

Comment: Also, (this is gonna sound really stupid bt i need to know) where exactly am I passing/storing the employeeId in the querystring??

Comment: it shows 0 in the employeeId...

Comment: context.Request.QueryString("employeeId") is null actually (as in "")

Comment: In the Image1.ImageUrl = ... you are setting the employee id

Comment: Also you don't need to call ProcessRequest(Context) from the page. Probably this is the reason why you are getting the error

Comment: so how(& where) do i call it then?
and where(& when) does this come into picture:
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" imageUrl="HttpHandler.ashx?employeeId=5"/>

Comment: You call it using the ImageUrl property

Comment: I really appreciate your help here but could you plz elaborate a little...

If I am not wrong you are talking about the image control in html... I cant seem to get the syntax rt for the image url.. this is what i have:

<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" imageUrl="HttpHandler.ashx?EmployeeID="18 />

Comment: the imageUrl attribute seems to be wrong. It should be: imageUrl="HttpHandler.ashx?EmployeeID=18"

Comment: "Input string was not in a correct format"...ughhhhh!!!!

Comment: I debugged the code and I think its got something to do with postback... I think the processrequest causes a postback... how can i avoid that?

Comment: You DON'T HAVE TO CALL the process request directly.. just via url... there is no postback. there is a get for the page and a get for each image you need.

Answer (score 0):

Generic Handler May helps you..

Answer (score 0):

your handler should be like this

```
Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
Dim employeeId As Integer
If (Not (context.Request.QueryString("employeeId")) Is Nothing) Then
employeeId = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString("employeeId"))
Dim con As SqlConnection("your connection string")    
Dim cmd As SqlCommand("select image_colum from <table_name> where employeeID = "+employeeID)
con.Open()
Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
dr.Read()
Dim picture As Byte() = dr[0]
context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
context.Response.BinaryWrite(picture)
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Error - "Response is not declared"

Comment: check now! use context.Response

Comment: "queryoutput is not declared"

Comment: and whats the difference between my code and yours...?
array name can be anything rt??

Comment: queryoutput means the result of your sql query

Comment: so what do I write there?? where do I get the output of my query??