# How to download the picture from database?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

How to download the picture from database using vb.net.

when i'm adding the productimage its inserted to the database.

```
 For Each file In radasync.UploadedFiles
            Dim ori_path = "../../productimage/"
            Dim path = Server.MapPath(ori_path)
            If System.IO.Directory.Exists(path) Then
                file.SaveAs(path & msGetGID & file.GetName)
            Else
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
                file.SaveAs(path & msGetGID & file.GetName)
            End If
            filepath = ori_path & msGetGID & file.GetName
        Next
msSQL = " update product" & _
            " set productimage= '" & filepath & "' " & _
            " where productname ='" & GID & "' "
```

how to download these images.....,

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="download" runat="server" ImageUrl="../../images/downloadfileformat.gif" />
```

how to write the vb code....,

Comment: have you try anything?

Comment: product image display in gridview?

Comment: Here is a similar answer in C# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935205/retrieve-image-from-database-in-asp-net/14935888#14935888

Comment: but, i want to download each product image in vb.net