# Extracting binary file from sql for viewing/saving to dir?

Tags: sql, asp.net, binary, etl

I am trying to rebuild a really bad website from scratch, what is the best way to display an image file stored in a table in SQL database?

Comment: 1st of all we need to know what format of image is.

Comment: its a .jpeg, is the only way to do this - a PowerShell way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935205/retrieve-image-from-database-in-asp-net

Comment: Thanks @BruceDunwiddie