# Returing file from DB but failing to write to FileStream

Tags: c#

I'm getting a request from my front end to get the file.

So I have a byte array saved in my SQL DB, I it looks like to use `File` result I need to return a `FileStream` converted from the byte array.

I tried following [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.writebyte(v=vs.110).aspx) to do this, using my byte array I get from my DB, but I get an error on the line

```
using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
{
```

> Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Test.docx' is denied.

Obviously, I know what's happening. It's using the `fileName` as path to find a file instead of creating a new file. Why is this happening? How do I return my byte array as a file in a FileStream? Should I even write file to disk if I need to return it in response?

Comment: Its not about the FileStream or bytes - read the error message.  You cannot do File IO to that folder and has been that way for many years.

Comment: Run visual studio as Administrator

Comment: I've edited the question as it looks like you are talking about some sort of WebServer returning a file response. Feel free to revert if this is not correct interpretation of the question. I used MVC version as duplicate, but if you need ASP one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935205/retrieve-image-from-database-in-asp-net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FileStream` is for dealing with files on disk. It would be inefficent to save the file to disk, then re-read it and return that to the user. Use a `MemoryStream` which takes a `byte[]`.

Since it sounds like you are using ASP.NET MVC, you can also just call `File` with your `byte[]`.

Comment: So in which case would `FileStream`'s [WriteByte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.writebyte(v=vs.110).aspx) be used? The `WriteByte` documentation, at least for me, seems to suggest it would be used in the case I thought because of the following line: "`The following code example shows how to write data to a file, byte by byte`". But obviously I misinterpreted that.

Comment: @JunKang its used when you want to write a single byte to disk.