# How to reference external image by URL in Report Designer?

Tags: acumatica

I need to dynamically include images on an Acumatica report.

I'd prefer not to attach the images to an Acumatica record as I'll have 10,000+ images within 12 months time. If I can reference by URL, I can utilize the image generation, caching and cleanup operations already in place on my web server.

When I try to setup a PictureBox in Report Designer as shown in the screenshot below, the image does not output on the report.

[image: Screenshot of Report Designer]

Any ideas? Is referencing an image by external URL supported in Acumatica? I've tried in both 2017r2 and 2019r1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly the S130 training then you can't use 'External' for accessing images by URL (http, https)

Note from S130 Training Course, page 176

> You can also show images uploaded to the site folder. If you were to
>   do that, for the image box, you would select Source as External and
>   specify the URL of the image in the Value property. For example, you
>   have uploaded the MyImage.png file to the /Site/ Images/ folder. In
>   the Value property, you should specify the following URL: Images/
>   MyImage.png.

Answer (score 1):

Report designer doesn't have option of showing external images ( images from external web sites ). That is done for security reasons. As a workaround I would recommend to use a page, inside of Acumatica, that will give you page from external source. For example you can create folder /ExternalDomains/getimage.aspx?id=imageID. Or even lighter version, create ashx handler, I just suppose you'll need to dig deeper into how to make it inside of Acumatica. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935205/retrieve-image-from-database-in-asp-net) is interesting link on ashx handlers, similar technologies can be googled for aspx pages.

Comment: A separate aspx page might be a workable strategy. I'll dig into it. But even so, within Report Designer, can you use a formula in the Value property when the Source property is "External"? E.g. `=Concat('/ExternalDomains/getImg.aspx?id=',[@imgId])`

Comment: For custom formulas make search on user defined functions in report designer of Acumatica